# Show that if a set $E$ has positive outer measure

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $E$ has finite measure and $\epsilon$ $\gt$ $0$, then $E$ is the disjoint union of a finite number of measurable sets, each of which has measure at most $\epsilon$.

My proof  (My teacher said that part of my proof still wrong, hope someone can help me to solve this proof ):

Since $u$ is an open subset of $R$, we can be written as a countable disjoint union of open intervals. Suppose first that the number of intervals is infinite, say : $u$ = $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty$ $I_k$

Where each $I_k$ is an open interval, we have :

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ $m^*$($I_k$) = $m^*(u)$ $\lt$ $\infty$

Since this series converges, there is some $n$ such that

$(*)$ $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ $m^*$($I_k$) $\lt$ $\epsilon$

We define $A$ by : $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n$ $I_k$

If there are only finitely many intervals in $u$, we can label them as $I_1,I_2, . . ,I_n$ and let $I_k=\varnothing$

For $k \ge n+1$, then we define $A=u$ and $(*)$ still hold, now we have $E\A$ ($E$ intersection $A$)$\subseteq A$, so :

$m^*$ ($E\A$) $\le$ $m^*$ ($u\A$)
$=$ $m^*$ ($u$) - $m^*$($A$)

=$\sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(I_k)- \sum_{k=1}^n m^*(I_k)$

=$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty m^* (I_k) \lt \epsilon$

On the other hand $A\E$ $\subseteq$ $u\E$, so $m^*(A\E) \le m^*(u\E) \lt \epsilon$

Comment: Let's start at the beginning and stop at the first mistake.  Whoa!  What's "$u$"?

Comment: Well persist and you can get some help here.  There are better ideas for approaching the problem but you can learn from a botched attempt anyway.  To speed things up (i) Check the problem: $E$ is likely assumed measurable otherwise you won't be happy. (ii) When you say "there is some $n$" it should have some kind of property otherwise it is just an uninvited guest to this party.  Etc.  BTW when your teacher says that "part of my proof is still wrong" consider that he is being exceedingly generous.

Answer (score 1):

*[Probably few appreciate the kind of answer here, where instead of answering the poster's question, one poses a series of related easier and harder questions.  Let me know if you don't like it and I may stop.]*

If there is a problem you can't solve then there is a harder problem you can't solve and probably even an *easier* problem you can't solve.  In this case here are several easier problems which I believe you can solve and which might give you a clue...and a few harder problems to ponder later.

> **Problem 1**.  Let $E=(0,1)$, i.e., the open interval with endpoints $0$ and
>   $1$. Show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite
>   pairwise-disjoint collection of measurable sets $\{E_1,E_2,\dots,
>   E_n\}$ so that each $E_i$ has Lebesgue measure smaller than $\epsilon$
>   and $\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i=E$.
>
> **Problem 2**.  Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $(0,1)$, i.e., a subset of the open interval with endpoints $0$ and
>   $1$. Show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite
>   pairwise-disjoint collection of measurable sets $\{E_1,E_2,\dots,
>   E_n\}$ so that each $E_i$ has Lebesgue measure smaller than $\epsilon$
>   and $\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i=E$.
>
> **Problem 3**.  Let $E$ be a measurable  set of finite measure. Show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there  are numbers
>   $-\infty<a<b<+\infty$ so that the sets $E\cap (-\infty,a)$ and  $E\cap
>   (b,\infty )$  are measurable sets each of which has Lebesgue measure
>   smaller than $\epsilon$.

After solving the first three problems the OP's problem should seem quite accessible:

> **Angelo's Problem**.  Let $E$ be a measurable subset of finite measure.  Show that, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite pairwise-disjoint
>   collection of measurable sets $\{E_1,E_2,\dots, E_n\}$ so that each
>   $E_i$ has Lebesgue measure smaller than $\epsilon$   and
>   $\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i=E$.

Now let's have more fun.

> **Harder Problem**.  Let $E$ be a measurable subset of finite measure equal to $1$ and let $n$ be a positive integer.  Show that  there is a finite pairwise-disjoint
>   collection of measurable sets $\{E_1,E_2,\dots, E_n\}$ so that each
>   $E_i$ has the same  Lebesgue measure    and
>   $\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i=E$.

This problem says that at a birthday party with a one pound, one-dimensional, cake you can split into $n$ equal weight pieces so no-one is shortchanged.

This suggests a much more interesting problem (which I quote from [Real Analysis](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/BBT-AlllChapters-Landscape.pdf) (BBT) Exercise 2:13.8 (Liaponoff's theorem):

> **Cake Problem**: Given a cake with $k$ ingredients (e.g., butter, sugar, chocolate,   garlic, etc.) each nonatomic and of unit mass and
>   mixed together in any "reasonable" way, it is possible to cut the cake
>   into $k$ pieces such that each of the pieces contains its share of
>   each of the ingredients.

Comment: Thomson thank you for your responses, i am so sorry. I am still not clear at all. From my explanation $u$ just a symbol to denote open interval. It's hard for me to prove.


This is my problem : 

Show that if $E$ has finite measure and $\epsilon$ $\gt$ $0$, then $E$ is the disjoint union of a finite number of measurable sets, each of which has measure at most $\epsilon$.

Comment: My advice is dump your present solution in the trash and work on problem #1.  Post your ideas and here and someone (or me) will help. If you cannot do it (quickly) for the choice $E=(0,1)$ then you have no hope of ever succeeding for a more general choice of $E$.  Test your intuition, always, with simpler examples to see if you are thinking correctly about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for any subset $E$ of reals with finite measure, and $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $K \subset E$ compact such that, $m(E\setminus K)<\epsilon$. The rest is up to you.